# lubuntu 14.04 - cairo-dock missfunctions

Tags: lubuntu, cairo-dock, transparency

I have a fresh installation of `lubuntu 14.04` on my acer AspireOne netbook and I wanted to add a dock to it. I decided to use `cairo-dock` since I use the exact same dock on my ubuntu laptop.

The thing is that I am experiencing a weird mul[image]function, as shown in the next figure

You can see that when there is a window open, hovering to make the dock pop-up, makes the desktop to appear. How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by compositing emulation provided by Cairo Dock. By right you should use real composition for jobs like this.

This is how you can get composition in Lubuntu 14.04

1. `sudo apt-get install compton`
2. Go to Applications menu, Preferences, Default Applications for Lxsession.
3. Go to autostart, add another startup process `compton -b`

Log out and log in back then you should able to use the dock nicely after disable Composition Emulation in Cairo settings.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Now it's really fixed!